# Is it possible to connect two routers using static routes over the Internet?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, routing

I have a [Dlink DSL 2750U ADSL2/2](http://www.dlink.co.in/products/?pid=452) Router at my home wherein I would like to connect it to a similar one at my office. I know about VPNs that can do the job but is it possible to establish such a connection using static routes? I don't know if this makes sense or is the right query.

Here is an image of how the setting appears on my Router:

[image]

Many thanks in advance.........

Comment: It's not clear what it is that you are trying to do. Both routers are already connected to the Internet. What do you mean by "connect it to a similar one at my office"? In what sense are they not already connected? Packets sent by one to the other's IP already leave over the connection to the ISP, right? So what routing do you think you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It (static routing) shouldn't work if you want to access local network behind router at your office or access home network from office because you can't route
[private IP ranges](http://whatismyipaddress.com/private-ip) over internet.

Since your routers doesn't support VPN, a simple solution is to connect both of your local networks (home and office) over VPN by setting up on one of your home's computer and one at your office computer VPN service such as [tinc](https://www.tinc-vpn.org/). `tinc` support bridging ethernet segments, this way both of your networks will be connected to each other over secure tunnel allowing you to run applications that normally only work in local area network

Comment: The main problem is not that you can't route private IP ranges (they're only forbidden in BGP, but perfectly routable e.g. if routes are configured statically); the main problem is that you cannot route to more than 1 hop away.

Comment: I generalized it as "it shouldn't work" :) , but actually technically you right, - the main restriction is in metrics

Comment: Thanks "Alex" for the Reply. I think so VPN is the best solution. I feel Static  Routes might be still possible one there a vpn between the private  networks like say routing to another network (LAN to WAN connection between routers)

Answer (score 0):

A static route is not enough here, since it can only determine the *immediate* next hop (and that nexthop must itself be directly reachable).

The reason being that IP doesn't have separate header fields to reference both the destination *and* some distant gateway. So when a route via some gateway is configured, its IP address is never really put in the packets – it's only used to look up the gateway's MAC address and the packets are sent to that MAC address. Therefore the gateway itself must already be local.

(Actually there's a feature that existed in IP long ago but has since been removed, called "source routing". It allowed packets to describe the full or partial path that the packet should go, overriding each router's own decision. However, it ended up being very useful for breaking into private networks, but nearly useless for legitimate tasks, and was later removed.)

That said, you don't need a "full" VPN to do what you want. The simplest possible method would be an IP-in-IP tunnel (or the slightly more common GRE tunnel), which wraps the whole packet including its 'LAN' addresses inside another IP header which now *can* hold the IP address of a remote gateway.

Unfortunately, the D-Link firmware can do no such thing...

Comment: Thank You so Much "grawity" for the reply.. Well the Dlink firmware does have something known as an IP Tunnel for this Model & Firmware Of Dlink. The Previous Model DSL 2730u had something as IP Sec, so could that work out for me.

Comment: @user182437: Plain IP or GRE tunnel should work, as long as you configure the same type _on both ends_. (Note that these tunnels aren't really secure though!) IPSec could also be used, either to secure the tunnel, or as a tunnel mechanism on its own – it's as secure as a good VPN, but difficult to configure.

Answer (score 0):

### What is a static route and when does it make sense?

**Short answer:** If both your home and your office are connected to the Internet, there is a good 99.99% chance that proper routing between them is already established.

**Long answer:** A static route is a simple route in the routing table that is created manually, and not by routing protocols such as RIP or OSPF. All this technical details aside, however, it only makes sense when you know for certain that what you need to perform is changing how routing occurs in your router.

On the Internet manual routing makes little sense though. There are simply so many elements that are out of your control, including but not limited to all the network devices that make connecting your home to your office possible.

### Connecting your home your office

To connect your home to your office, the following prerequisites need to be established first:

1. Either or both must have a public IP. (Yes, yes, people in the comment section will probably point out that it is possible to connect to a server that is behind a NAT if certain conditions are met. But all comes down to this: One public IP under *some degree* of your control is need. Period.) The location that has a public IP can accept incoming connections, allowing the other location to connect to it.
2. Services that want to connect to must be configured, e.g., if you wish to share files between home and office, the File and Printer Sharing service must be installed and configured at your office or home.

The rest is really client-specific: i.e. for sharing files, you open File Explorer, type `\\` in the address bar followed by the IP address of your office server and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then you type in a username and password.

Also, you must know that without VPN, your connection may or may not be secure. e.g., file and printer sharing connection is not secure, but connection to an internal office web server that supports HTTPS is secure.

Comment: "...you open File Explorer, type \\ in the address bar followed by the IP address..." - do not do that ever without encapsulation over secure tunnel ! "\\" assumes windows share which haven't brute-force prevention mechanism that will lead to disaster at some point in time if one allow access from wild internet to such resources.

Comment: Thanks so much "Fleet Command" for your effort. So is it that I need to disable NAT on my router or setting up a DMZ pointing to my PC or Server. My PC in that case will need to have a Powerful Internet Security System while keeping the fact extremely important that encryption will be necessary... Otherwise the network will be bound to brute force attacks..